# Date Comparison - Condition fails, but returns True

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to compare a date against the first of next month from last year.  If the date from date1 is less than the first of next month from last year then I want it to return true.  The condition only seems to fail if I set the date to one year ahead.

```
LastRightToKnow = 7/14/2011
Dim RTK As String
RTK = ""
If [NeedsRightToKnow] = -1 And [LastRightToKnow] < DateSerial(Year(Now() - 1), Month(Now() + 1), 1) Then
RTK = "Right-To-Know"
End If
```

So, from my understanding, I gather that if `today = 6/14/2012` then

```
DateSerial(Year(Now() - 1), Month(Now() + 1), 1)  = 7/01/2011 
LastRightToKnow = 7/14/2011
```

therefore `7/14/2011  < 7/01/2011` should return `False`.  However it returns `true`... What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Now() +1 = tomorrow
```

I think you mean

```
DateSerial(Year(Now())-1, Month(Now())-1, 1)  = 7/01/2011
```

Comment: Yep, your right.  Thanks alot.  Been staring at this thing for an hour trying to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

Your formula is off because of the placement of the parethesis:

```
? DateSerial(Year(Now() - 1), Month(Now() + 1), 1)
6/1/2012 
? DateSerial(Year(Now()) - 1, Month(Now()) + 1, 1)
7/1/2011
```

Edit: need to do the same for month

Comment: You had it faster. I didn't have Access open was fumbling around in the immediate window.